# When visualizing graph clusters, prevent convex hulls from overlapping

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, convex-hull

I have a 2-d graph partitioned into 25 clusters. The cluster shapes are complex and in some cases adjacent. Here is a script that will generate a simplified example of what my results look like:

```
library(factoextra)
km.res <- kmeans(iris[, -5], 3)

fviz_cluster(km.res, iris[, -5]) +
  scale_color_brewer('Cluster', palette='Set2') + 
  scale_fill_brewer('Cluster', palette='Set2') +
  scale_shape_manual('Cluster', values=c(22,23,24)) + 
  ggtitle(label='')
```

[image: Example]

Notice that the convex hulls for clusters 1 and 2 overlap. Presumably, if there were more line segments making up the convex hull (or "outline" or "polygon", whatever you want to call it) the shapes would not need to overlap or the overlap would be minimal. Is there a way to draw a more "contoured" convex hull for the cluster? In other words, is there a way to draw a polygon around the cluster that fits it as tightly as possible?

For instance, in the southernmost portion of cluster 2. Point 132 connects to point 118, which connects to point 119. 132->118->119. If there were more segments, the shape would be more complex but more "form fitting". E.g., 132->118->110->136->106->123->119. Maybe another way to phrase this question would be, how can I specify that the convex hull should occupy the smallest area possible while still encompassing all points of a given cluster?

Comment: Do you specifically need a convex hull? In your specific example, the resulting polygon is not convex. Are you using the bounding box for anything besides visualization? I don't know what the specific code would be but may try searching for concave hulls or radial sorting (then use to draw a perimeter).

Comment: Thanks, this is good advice. I'll take a look at concave or otherwise non-convex hulls. To answer your question, the bounding box is only used for visualization in my use case.